# (Koa.js) Generators and yield basics

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I'm trying to understand how generators work (generally and in koa). I have files:

**Rooms.js** - it handles placing user to room (socket.io) and stuff, when player is assigned to the room I want to run `Game.js` module

```js
var Game = require('./Game');
(...)
Game.startGame(roomId)
```

**Game.js** - function `startGame*()` is called from Rooms.js: and it should do some code, then I want it to wait let's say 500ms, and after that it should run some more code.

```js
exports.startGame = function *(roomid) {
  console.log("before sleep")
  yield Utility.sleep(500)
  console.log("after sleep")
}
```

and sleep() function in **Utility.js**:

```js
exports.sleep = function(ms){
  return function(cb) {
    setTimeout(cb, ms);
  };
}
```

But it doesn't work - the generator function in Game.js. And I don't have any clue what is wrong there. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators must be acted on by outside code, a 'runner' such as the [co](https://github.com/tj/co) library.

Koajs uses the co library under the covers, so any middleware is run by co.

Its not clear to me if you are running Game.startGame(roomId) inside a runner (koajs middleware), and since it's a generator you must yield it (which your code is missing).

I have a screencast on Generators that you might find helpful

http://knowthen.com/episode-2-understanding-javascript-generators/

Here is an example of your code (compressed to one file) that is runnable:

```
// example.js
'use strict';
let co = require('co');

let startGame = function *(roomid) {
  console.log("before sleep")
  yield sleep(500)
  console.log("after sleep")
}

let sleep = function (ms){
  return function(cb){
    setTimeout(cb, ms);
  }
}

co(function *(){
  // your code was missing yield
  yield startGame(123);
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

here is the output:

```
$node example.js
before sleep
after sleep
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right, i didn't understand before that generator must be yield from outside of it. Also, your screencast was _very_  informative and I hope helped me even better understand generators. :)